# cannot import python modules despite having installed them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip, plotly-python

I have installed both `plotly.express` and `pandas` using:

```
pip install plotly-express
```

and

```
pip install pandas
```

I have tried to import these modules into my program using

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
```

however, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` for both these packages on run.

---

I have tried using alternate installs like:

```
py -3 -m pip install plotly-express
python -m pip install plotly-express
py -m pip install plotly-express
```

When I try install these packages again, they say that the requirement is already satisfied in `c:\python38\lib\site-packages`. All my other packages are installed at `C:\Users\Oli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages` (I am Oli !).

I think this might be the issue. I've read that it is a bad idea to just stick in these files directly.

How can I get these imports to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to do is to check that the directory `C:\python38\lib\site-packages` is in your [`PYTHONPATH`](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html) environment variable. If not, add it or create `PYTHONPATH` as environment variable if it doesn't exist and add the directory (for Windows, Start -> type "Edit Environment Variables for your Account").

Alternatively, try the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\python38\lib\site-packages')
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: vscode still gives me an error for this, but I am now able to run from cmd, so I guess it'll do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a path problem.
Have you updated py recently in your machine? I once had a problem like this after updating, I could only solve it by completely uninstalling all versions first then reinstalling all from scratch. A bit of work, sure, but at least for me solved like a charm!