# Importing a module throws ModuleNotFoundError even after module is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to install pyperclip on Python 3.8.6 on Windows 10, and after typing
`pip3 install pyperclip`
in cmd it tells me that pyperclip has been successfully installed, but when I then try `import pyperclip` on they Python shell I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling pyperclip using pip, and also installing an older version of the package (1.8.0) but the error persists.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try inside a virtual environment like Conda? Maybe you need to install a dependency. I will try inside a conda environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot import python modules despite having installed them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384294/cannot-import-python-modules-despite-having-installed-them)